# How to play a sound file while running a program in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, mpv

I'm creating an alarm clock script as I haven't found a good Linux alarm yet and I decided it would be a good idea to learn Bash scripting(again). I'm looking into making a program that plays an alarm sound(beep beep full volume) and I want the program to make me solve some basic algebra before it turns off the sound. However I can't figure out how to play the sound at the same time it's asking for solutions and waiting for my input so it could turn the noise off. I really don't even know what expression I would use to force mpv to act strictly in the background. `&` and `;` wait for the line to terminate and I wasn't able to solve it by using `parallel`. I also tried to direct output to `/dev/null` because that seemed to be the answer for other people but it doesn't work for my problem(nothing happens until mpv terminates, which only seems obvious because it only ignores output right?).

Here's what I've done so far(extremely basic and only has the structure so I can program with it):

```
 # !/bin/zsh

 function math (){ 
     echo MATH
     read answer
     if (( ("$answer") == $1 )); then
         echo PASS    
     else
         echo FAIL
     fi  
 }

 echo 'Alarm'

 let "NUM1=(($RANDOM % 10) * 3)";
 let "NUM2=(($RANDOM % 10) * 3)";

 let "m = $NUM1 * $NUM2"

 printf "%d * %d = %d" "$NUM1" "$NUM2" "$m"

 mpv alarm_sound.wav ; #>/dev/null 2>&1
 math m
```

`echo MATH` comes after `mpv` has finished playing the sound.

My dream would be to have `mpv` to act as a completely independent process so that it affects `alarm.sh` in no way and then `kill -9 mpv` once the if condition "passes".

I'm completely lost - thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at Bash's `coproc` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual with Linux, there are many viable solutions to your dilemma.

The most simple that comes to mind is to enter the `&` sign at the end of your command:

```
mpv audio_file.wav &
```

This should spawn a new process for the audio file.

Comment: Thanks. I actually thought about `&` but I didn't realize the two commands have to be on a separate line. I tried putting it like `command1 & command2` as if they would run stimulatenously but obviously it's does a very different thing. Typing `command1 &` on one line and `command2` on another line works.